# Oracle custom sort list of rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-order-by

I have wrote a query which return some gatelist with total entry and exit. I wanted to sort them by custom sort.
I have gave order by gate asc but this only sorting alphabetically, I want to sort it customly like below

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional ordering. You did not really gave the rules that you want to implement, but based on your sample data this could look like:

```
order by case 
    when gate like 'Gate%' then 0
    when gate = 'CPAR' then 1
    when gate = 'NCY' then 2
    when gate like 'CCT%' then 3
    when gate like 'NCT%' then 4
    else 5
end,
gate
```